# Does any country actually require visitors to have physical cash in hands to be allowed entry to the country?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, proof-provenance-of-funds

I [read](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/184951/1810):

> Many countries (like those in Schengen) which have clear numbers don't actually require you to have that in cash, just have access to the necessary funds (and I believe there are exceptions if you are staying at someone else's place, etc.) [author: jcaron]

This makes me wonder: Does any country actually require visitors to have physical cash in hands to be allowed entry to the country? Let's ignore the case where one needs to pay some visa on arrival with cash, or other entry fees/bribes.

Comment: In past (not sure it is still applicable), Uzbekistan required to have cash, and that you change the cash there (at official exchange at border). I assume similar things happened (and still happens) on the few countries with controlled exchange (also to reduce black market, which it is out of government control).

Comment: It's most probably changed these days, but Japan used to require you have ¥2,000 to **leave.** That would be fun if you only found out at the airport, as Japan's ATMs at the time were not international-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Thailand does, for people applying for a visa on arrival. They require you show proof of 10,000 THB for a single person, besides the 2K for the visa fee. Whether this is checked every single time, I have no idea but suspect it is mostly enforced on a case by case basis, especially with citizens of countries deemed suspicious, or with travellers who themselves look dodgy.

I know people (Chinese), who've been asked to show proof of funds during the visa application.

Comment: Proof of funds and having actual cash in hand are quite different things. Most counties which require proof of funds (during a visa application or at the border) will be happy with a payment card and showing that there’s money on the account, they don’t actually require you to have notes and coins in hand.

Comment: Well, the people I know who were asked to show proof of funds had cash with them, and showed that, which satisfied the Immigration officers. While China is mostly cashless, they tend to travel with cash.

Comment: Yes but the question is about countries which actually require you to show cash and wouldn't accept alternatives.